# How can I step to use the python debugger to break at every function call?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I want to closely monitor the chain of function calls which are called from a certain function.

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
res = api.InsertVideoEntry(video_entry, video)
```

I'm looking for a way to easily see that `api.insertVideoEntry(video_entry, video)` calls `foo()` which calls `bar()` which calls `baz()`,

Here's a really crude diagram to show what I mean.  I don't need it in this form, but this is the kind kind of information I'm looking for.

```
api.insertVideoEntry()
    foo()
        bar()
            baz()
            baz2()
        log()
    finish()
```

Comment: Also, I don't have time to test and write up a complete answer right now, but take a look at the `inspect` module. (In particular the functions for examining frames.)

Comment: Are you interested in alternatives which do not use `pdb`?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower, your answer is great, thank you. I would have accepted it sooner but I hadn't seen it.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an interesting learning experience to write up. Maybe you can use the code shown here? [This demonstration](http://ideone.com/W3scL) should give you an idea of the type of output you can expect when using `trace`.

```
# Functions to trace
# ==================

def baz():
    pass

def baz2():
    pass

def bar():
    baz()
    baz2()

def log():
    pass

def foo():
    bar()
    log()

def finish():
    pass

def insertVideoEntry():
    foo()
    finish()

# Names to trace
# ==============

names = list(locals())

# Machinery for tracing
# =====================

import os
import sys

def trace(start, *names):
    def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'call':
            code = frame.f_code
            name = code.co_name
            if name in names:
                level = -start
                while frame:
                    frame = frame.f_back
                    level += 1
                print('{}{}.{}()'.format(
                    '    ' * level,
                    os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(code.co_filename))[0],
                    name))
                return tracefunc
    sys.settrace(tracefunc)

# Demonstration of tracing
# ========================

trace(2, *names)

insertVideoEntry()
```

If you are interested in a recursive demo, you might like [this variation](http://ideone.com/ltcnQ8) with a called arguments readout:

```
import os
import sys

def main(discs):
    a, b, c = list(range(discs, 0, -1)), [], []
    line = '-' * len(repr(a))
    print(a, b, c, sep='\n')
    for source, destination in towers_of_hanoi(discs, a, b, c):
        destination.append(source.pop())
        print(line, a, b, c, sep='\n')

def towers_of_hanoi(count, source, via, destination):
    if count > 0:
        count -= 1
        yield from towers_of_hanoi(count, source, destination, via)
        yield source, destination
        yield from towers_of_hanoi(count, via, source, destination)

def trace(start, *names):
    def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'call':
            code = frame.f_code
            name = code.co_name
            if name in names:
                level = -start
                args = ', '.join(repr(frame.f_locals[name]) for name in
                                 code.co_varnames[:code.co_argcount])
                while frame:
                    frame = frame.f_back
                    level += 1
                print('{}{}.{}({})'.format(
                    ' ' * (level * 4),
                    os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(code.co_filename))[0],
                    name, args))
                return tracefunc
    sys.settrace(tracefunc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trace(3, 'main', 'towers_of_hanoi')
    main(3)
```

Comment: Great answer @NoctisSkytower!  Follow up question though -- what about scenarios where I don't know ahead of time the functions that are going to be called?  I originally wanted this so I could see the flow of control when calling a method of a GData object.  The Youtube/GData modules aren't exactly light and I was looking for the easiest way to see which functions call which functions (so I could more easily hack a few changes which I needed to make).

Comment: @StuartPowers: You could probably replace the line of code `if name in names:` with `if True:` to see all of the calls being made. BTW, a new example has been added that allows you to see what arguments the function was called with.